# Visual Studio. How to manually Break debugging thread

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, break

I attach my Visual Studio Project to one application while debugging.

Sometimes I need to stop the debugging but it also close the attached process. It is not convinient because it takes a lot of time to load.

The "break all" button of VS appears grey and disable.

Can I so something to solve it?

Comment: Well, the debugger has to be attached to the process in order for the debugging features to work.

Comment: @ChrisO it is attached, I just want to "break it" from the process or stop it but no the process which is attached

Comment: Unfortunately, when you are attached using the native debugger, then detaching from the process will also kill the process.  By any chance do you have a native app?  Or is it only managed code?  If it is only managed code, then you can set the debugger type to managed only, then this case you can detach from your app without stopping the program.

Comment: Does Debug|Detach all menum item work for you?